# Create own Directus image from dockerfile

Tags: docker, directus

I downloaded Directus.io repo https://github.com/directus/directus and I want to create own image. How to do it using Dockerfile.

I tried to run script from repo docker https://github.com/directus/docker but i got error with message:

```
Step 7/13 : COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./directus/ /var/directus/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder151402968/directus: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `Dockerfile` from our project which works just fine:

```
#
# Final image
#
FROM directus/directus:v8-apache

#
# Filesystem & permissions
#
COPY ./rootfs/ /

RUN chmod +x install.sh

#
# Port
#
EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ./install.sh
```

In the same directory we have `rootfs` dir with a content what we want to override from Directus, e.g. config files, some CSS etc...

```
/rootfs
  var
    directus
      public
        admin
          style.css
      src
      install.sh
```

Our `install.sh` script contains some stuff we need to run on startup. The most important is to start Apache in the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ...
# Our custom scripts 
# ...

apache2-foreground
```